# MySql Procedure call in c# returns no rows

Tags: c#, mysql

I have seen many post over here on stack overflow with the same issue mentioned as title. But still my problem is not solved from that so dont mark it as duplicate just now as I really need to understand the reason and find a solution for this.
I have a procedure that is working fine in workbench but not when calling from C#.

Here is my c# code :

```
public List<object> GetScheduleTest(string building,int sem, int week, int day, string userid)
    {
        List<object> idata = new List<object>();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
        using(MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
        {
            try
            {
                if (cn.State != ConnectionState.Open) { cn.Open(); }
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetScheduleTest", cn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("build", building);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sem", sem);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("weekno", week);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("daynum", day);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userid", userid);                        
                    MySqlDataAdapter mySqlData = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    mySqlData.Fill(dt);                        
                }
                idata.Add(dt);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }               
        }
        return idata;
    }
```

Here is mysql procedure. Its a bit big.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetScheduleTest`(build varchar(45), weekno int, sem int,daynum int, userid varchar(45))
BEGIN
set @uid=userid;
set @semno = sem;
set @dayno = daynum;
set @daynumreserve = daynum+1;
set @weeknum = weekno;
set @building = build;
SET @sql := CONCAT('
 create or replace view  View_resultScheduleDayWeek as 
  SELECT sc.classname, ifnull(concat(case when section = 11 then coursename  end),'' '') AS `section11`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 5 then coursename  end),'' '') AS `section5`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 6 then coursename  end),'' '') AS `section6`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 7 then coursename  end),'' '') AS `section7`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 9 then coursename  end),'' '') AS `section9` ,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 1 then coursename end),'' '') AS `section1`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 2 then coursename  end),'' '') AS `section2`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 3 then coursename end),'' '') AS `section3`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 4 then coursename end),'' '') AS `section4` ,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 8 then coursename end),'' '') AS `section8`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 10 then coursename end),'' '') AS `section10`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 12 then coursename  end),'' '') AS `section12` 
  FROM schedule sc where weekStart<=',@weeknum,' and weekend >=',@weeknum,' and 
  sc.classname in (select classname from classdetails where teachingBuilding=''',@building,''' and classname in
  (select classid from userlocationaccess where userserialnum =(select serialno from userdetails where loginid= ''',@uid,'''))) 
    and Sem =',@semno,' and dayno =',@dayno,' GROUP BY  section,sc.classname 
 union
SELECT classroom as classname, ifnull(concat(case when section = 11 then concat( purpose,'':reserve:'',Status)  end),'' '') AS `section11`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 5 then concat( purpose,'':reserve:'',Status)  end),'' '') AS `section5`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 6 then concat( purpose,'':reserve:'',Status)  end),'' '') AS `section6`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 7 then concat( purpose,'':reserve:'',Status)  end),'' '') AS `section7`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 9 then concat( purpose,'':reserve:'',Status)  end),'' '') AS `section9` ,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 1 then concat( purpose,'':reserve:'',Status) end),'' '') AS `section1`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 2 then concat( purpose,'':reserve:'',Status)  end),'' '') AS `section2`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 3 then concat( purpose,'':reserve:'',Status) end),'' '') AS `section3`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 4 then concat( purpose,'':reserve:'',Status) end),'' '') AS `section4` ,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 8 then concat( purpose,'':reserve:'',Status) end),'' '') AS `section8`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 10 then concat( purpose,'':reserve:'',Status) end),'' '') AS `section10`,
ifnull(concat(case when section = 12 then concat( purpose,'':reserve:'',Status)  end),'' '') AS `section12` 
 FROM schedulereserve where classroom in (select classname from classdetails where teachingbuilding=''',@building,''' and classname in
  (select classid from userlocationaccess where userserialnum =(select serialno from userdetails where loginid= ''',@uid,''')))
  and week =',@weeknum,' and Status !=''Rejected'' and semester =',@semno,' and weekday(date) =',@daynumreserve,' GROUP BY  section,classroom
  union
  SELECT newclass as classname, ifnull(concat(case when newsection = 11 then concat( courseid ,'':transfer:'',currentstatus) end),'' '') AS `section11`,
ifnull(concat(case when newsection = 5 then concat( courseid ,'':transfer:'',currentstatus)  end),'' '') AS `section5`,
ifnull(concat(case when newsection = 6 then concat(courseid ,'':transfer:'',currentstatus)  end),'' '') AS `section6`,
ifnull(concat(case when newsection = 7 then concat(courseid ,'':transfer:'',currentstatus)  end),'' '') AS `section7`,
ifnull(concat(case when newsection = 9 then concat(courseid ,'':transfer:'',currentstatus)  end),'' '') AS `section9` ,
ifnull(concat(case when newsection = 1 then concat(courseid ,'':transfer:'',currentstatus) end),'' '') AS `section1`,
ifnull(concat(case when newsection = 2 then concat(courseid ,'':transfer:'',currentstatus)  end),'' '') AS `section2`,
ifnull(concat(case when newsection = 3 then concat(courseid ,'':transfer:'',currentstatus) end),'' '') AS `section3`,
ifnull(concat(case when newsection = 4 then concat(courseid ,'':transfer:'',currentstatus) end),'' '') AS `section4` ,
ifnull(concat(case when newsection = 8 then concat(courseid ,'':transfer:'',currentstatus) end),'' '') AS `section8`,
ifnull(concat(case when newsection = 10 then concat(courseid ,'':transfer:'',currentstatus) end),'' '') AS `section10`,
ifnull(concat(case when newsection = 12 then concat(courseid ,'':transfer:'',currentstatus) end),'' '') AS `section12` 
 FROM scheduletransfer where newweek<=',@weeknum,' and newweek >=',@weeknum,' and newclass in 
 (select classname from classdetails where teachingbuilding=''',@building,''' and classname in
  (select classid from userlocationaccess where userserialnum =(select serialno from userdetails where loginid= ''',@uid,'''))) and 
 idref in (select id from schedule where sem=',@semno,') and newday =',@dayno,' GROUP BY  newsection,newclass');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

select row_number() OVER() AS RowNumber , classname, max(section1) as section1, max(section2) as section2,
max(section3)as section3,
max(section4)as section4,
max(section5)as section5,
max(section6)as section6,max(section7)as section7,
max(section8)as section8,
max(section9)as section9,max(section10)as section10,
max(section11)as section11,
max(section12)as section12 from View_resultScheduleDayWeek group by classname;
END
```

These was working till yesterday without any issues. I tried to make some changes for paging in the procedure. That also was working absolutely fine on database side. But once I made changes which included an output parameter on c# side. This procedure stopped giving results from c#. and now its earlier version which is given above is also not working through c#.
I tried all the possible solutions from different post but nothing seems to work. and as there is no exception I dont get the reason.
Please suggest something.
Let me know if you need any more details. Thanks

Comment: I don't have your DB to test it, but I'd try manually running the raw sql statement in SSMS or visual studio to see if it works.

Comment: I see you have a `try{ ... } catch {}`, so any errors that are happening are just thrown away. That's always a bad idea. You're probably getting a really useful error message but because you're throwing it away, it's no longer of any help

Comment: @CaiusJard if there is any error wont the control come to catch block? and this is all in debugging I can see the exception while its in catch block. or can there be a case where there is a error but control would not transfer to catch?

Comment: What ADO.NET library are you using (MySql.Data or MySqlConnector) and what version? What MySQL Server (MySQL, Aurora, MariaDB, etc.) are you using, and what version?

Comment: @BradleyGrainger MySql.Data and MYSQL 8.0.17 moslty to be exact

Comment: I just checked the view that I was creating. so when I called procedure from workbench, the view had a few rows according to the conditions. but when I called the procedure from c# and then I checked the view in database(through workbench),  view is empty. No rows. and its the same procedure with same parameter values from both the sides. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: The procedure must be accessed using `CALL procedure_name(parameters)` query. Test something like `using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CALL GetScheduleTest('build', weekno, sem, daynum, 'userid')", cn))`.

Comment: @Akina ok.. let me test that

Comment: @Ushaphulwani only if you step; we get high numbers of users that show up here with an empty catch block saying "my code doesn't throw any errors, but doesn't produce any output" and mostly turns out they threw away a useful error

Comment: @CaiusJard I understand that and this try catch block without any other useful code is just for stepping into it in case of exception and see the data in ex variable. Again this is just for debugging purpose for the time being. But as you are saying I will remove this try catch and then run the code and see what happens. Give me 2 minutes for that

Comment: There are better ways of doing it that, btw.. On debug menu, choose "Exceptions" then put a tick next to "CLR Exceptions". Now VS will break as soon as an exception is thrown, even if it is in a catch.. And you can see the faulting code as soon as the exception occurs rather than much higher up the call stack where the catch might be

Comment: @CaiusJard I did the way you suggested, checking the CLR Exceptions in Exception Settings.. but still got no error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this thing you've chosen to do, of creating a view and selecting from it, inside a SP, is a bad idea, but it would seem to contain the answer to your problem

Your complaint is that when you run this SP in WB, it produces (and leaves behind) a view that does produce results. When you run the SP from C#, it produces a view that has no results when queried.

I thus propose you clone this SP to a new name, and adjust the clone so that it creates a view with a slightly different name. Run one from C#, the other from WB..

..then pull the code of each view back out of the DB and run them through a diff tool to look at the differences. Aside from the name, there *must* be some critical difference between the two

---

When you resolve the problem, I would switch away from this method of creating a new view every time you run the SP, and use a WITH instead.

Don't do:

```
@sql = 'CREATE VIEW x AS SELECT y FROM z;'
EXECUTE @sql;
SELECT * FROM x;
```

Just do:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT y FROM z;)
SELECT * FROM x;
```

Comment: I will try your way.. by creating different procedure and views and see what happens. and then I will change it to x format

Comment: Thank you so much.. comparing them showed that there is a difference of a space in one of the values.. and so there was no data coming in the view and trust me I was stuck since yesterday and I've checked values everytime I debugged but I couldnt see it.. Thank you. and I will remove view and select the data like above